# Scrolling profiles of most recent members

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scroll, simplyscroll

I have a file recent.php that shows recent 15 members who has joined my website. Since 15 is a big number, I wish to have a scrolling effect on the page so that all recent 15 profiles will keep scrolling. Then I came across [SimplyScroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/) but here is the issue that I am facing.
I downloaded the script and went through all the test files and I have understood how to do it if I have static images but dont know how to do it when there is a dynamic data that comes from database in form of html table (top 15 registered members and their profiles. Can someone help me where to make changes to get the scrolling effect? Here is the code of recent.php Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start()

include("connect/config.php");
if($_SESSION['gender123'])
{
    if($_SESSION['gender123']=='Male')
    {
     $gender="where gender='Female'";
    }
    else
    {
     $gender="where gender='Male'";     
    }       
}
$sql="select * from register $gender order by index_id DESC LIMIT 0,15";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());    
$abcdef=$_SESSION['userid'];
$select="select * from payments where pmatri_id='$abcdef' or pemail='$abcdef'";
$exe=mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
$fetch123=mysql_fetch_array($exe);
?>


<table width="210px" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="text2">

    <tr valign="top">

        <?php while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

        <td valign="top" align="left" height="55px" style="padding:1px; max-width:120px; min-width:120px;">
            <?php if($_SESSION[ 'userid']) { if($fetch123[ 'profile']-$fetch123[ 'r_profile']>0) { ?>
            <a href="memprofile.php?user_id=<?php echo $fetch['matri_id']; ?>">

                <?php if($fetch[ 'photo1_approve']=="No" ) { ?>
                <img src="images/No-Image-icon.png" height="100" width="90px" border="0" />
                <?php } else if($fetch[ 'photo1']=='' ) { ?>
                <img src="images/No-Image-icon.png" height="100" width="90px" border="0" />
                <?php } else if($fetch[ 'photo_protect']=='Yes' ) { ?>
                <img src="images/imagePassProtected.jpg" height="100" width="90px" border="0" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                <img src="photos/<?php echo $fetch['photo1']?>" height="100" width="90px" border="0" />
                <?php } ?>
                <br />
                <h3><?php echo $fetch['firstname']." ".$fetch['lastname']; ?></h3>
            </a>
         </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue, but ok.. here I go: Please stop using `mysql_*`. It has been deprecated for over 2 years now and it leaves you wide open to SQL injection. Considder upgrading to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with Prepared Statements. Also, while you're add it, please use CSS for styling instead of HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will consider MySQLi. The code is working fine but I need help in scrolling effect with the simplyscroll JQuery if you can shed some light on changes that I need to the above code.

Comment: Not before you've updated your code. We both know you're not going to do it and just want someone to fix it for you. I however know you're going to be back here sooner or later because everything went to hell. Don't get me wrong. I do want to help you! But I'm not going to work on such a messy code and only make it worse.

Comment: Sorry if you felt offended. I dont want to fix this code, it is working properly. i wanted help from someone who can help me add the scrolling effect coz im not understanding how to do it in html tables with no css. Here is a working fiddle with css but i dont need css and my file has tables. http://jsfiddle.net/uruwf/3/ I dont know if it is even possible if I dont want to have css. Eagerly awaiting a solution with atleast a startup on how can i go about achieving it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing. Whether it is in a table or outside of a table. It's always the same procedure.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() { //on DOM ready
    $(".scroller").simplyScroll({
      orientation: 'horizontal',
      auto: true,
      manualMode: 'loop',
      frameRate: 20,
      speed: 5
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.simply-scroll-container {
  /* Container DIV - automatically generated */
  position: relative;
}
.simply-scroll-clip {
  /* Clip DIV - automatically generated */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.simply-scroll-list {
  /* UL/OL/DIV - the element that simplyScroll is inited on */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.simply-scroll-list li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.simply-scroll-list li img {
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
.simply-scroll-btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(buttons.png);
  width: 42px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-left {
  left: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-position: 0 -44px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-left.disabled {
  background-position: 0 0 !important;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-left:hover,
.simply-scroll-btn-left:focus {
  background-position: 0 -88px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-right {
  right: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-position: -84px -44px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-right.disabled {
  background-position: -84px 0 !important;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-right:hover,
.simply-scroll-btn-right:focus {
  background-position: -84px -88px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-up {
  right: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  background-position: -126px -44px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-up.disabled {
  background-position: -126px 0 !important;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-up:hover,
.simply-scroll-btn-up:focus {
  background-position: -126px -88px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-down {
  right: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-position: -42px -44px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-down.disabled {
  background-position: -42px 0 !important;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-down:hover,
.simply-scroll-btn-down:focus {
  background-position: -42px -88px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-pause {
  right: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-position: -168px -44px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-pause:hover,
.simply-scroll-btn-pause:focus {
  background-position: -168px -88px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-pause.active {
  background-position: -84px -44px;
}
.simply-scroll-btn-pause.active:hover,
.simply-scroll-btn-pause.active:focus {
  background-position: -84px -88px;
}
/* Custom class modifications - override classees

.simply-scroll is default

*/

.simply-scroll {
  /* Customisable base class for style override DIV */
  width: 576px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-clip {
  width: 576px;
  height: 200px;
}
.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li {
  float: left;
  width: 290px;
  height: 200px;
}
.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li img {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-left {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-left.disabled {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-left:hover {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-right {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-right.disabled {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-right:hover {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-up {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-up.disabled {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-up:hover {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-down {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-down.disabled {} .simply-scroll .simply-scroll-btn-down:hover {}
/* Vertical scroller example */

.vert {
  /* wider than clip to position buttons to side */
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.vert .simply-scroll-clip {
  width: 290px;
  height: 400px;
}
.vert .simply-scroll-list {} .vert .simply-scroll-list li {
  width: 290px;
  height: 200px;
}
.vert .simply-scroll-list li img {} .vert .simply-scroll-btn {} .vert .simply-scroll-btn-up {
  /* modified btn pos */
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.vert .simply-scroll-btn-up.disabled {} .vert .simply-scroll-btn-up:hover {} .vert .simply-scroll-btn-down {
  /* modified btn pos */
  right: 0;
  top: 52px;
}
.vert .simply-scroll-btn-down.disabled {} .vert .simply-scroll-btn-down:hover {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/jquery.simplyscroll.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="scroller">
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img1.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img2.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img3.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img4.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://www.budowastrony.pl/images/img5.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="scroller">
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img1.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img2.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img3.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://budowastrony.pl/images/img4.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://www.budowastrony.pl/images/img5.jpg" width="290" height="200">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" value="" />
```

You might want to change from an id to a class when there are multiple rows you want to affect like I did in the example above. But the other things dont change.

I hope my example makes it clear how to work with it. If you really got multiple Slides it is important to change from id to class and do the same thing in your js code ( id="scroller" to class="scroller", $("#scroller") to $(".scroller") )

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem i face is that, in your example, the table is static and my requirement is dynamic where table is generated by the code (while loop). Your example has static images and in my requirement, the data is pulled from the server which has two parts (an image & first/last name). This is where I get confused especially on the syntax part. I will see the class methodology and will get back here. Thanks.

Comment: phew! somehow i managed to get the profiles scrolling with an issue. I have set 4 profiles to scroll but when the first profile reaches extreme left, the scrolling starts again and overlaps the previous four profiles. It doesnt look good. Ideally, all four profiles should scroll to left and when the fourth profile disappears thats when the loop should start. This does not happen. I also tried removing <table parameters> and <td parameters> with no help. Any suggestion? Sorry but I cannot show the exact behaviour for some reason. Thanks

Comment: I am assuming something wrong in `<?php while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>` It gives me a feeling that there is something with the loop because of which it is overlapping. `$result` has the top 15 and top 4 profiles. Any ideas???

Comment: The syntax of your code looks alright in the snippet you posted. I can't see any mistakes there. But there are also variables that i don't see where they come from ( $fetch123 is not defined and used there for example ).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate you looking into it. I have edited the original post with all variables. Do let me know if something can be done.